# How to use custom route middleware with Sails.js? (ExpressJS)

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

I've just unpacked a fresh copy of the Node framework Sails.js.  It is built on Express 3.  In the /config/routes.js file is this comment:

```
/**
 * (1) Core middleware
 *
 * Middleware included with `app.use` is run first, before the router
 */


/**
 * (2) Static routes
 *
 * This object routes static URLs to handler functions--
 * In most cases, these functions are actions inside of your controllers.
 * For convenience, you can also connect routes directly to views or external URLs.
 *
 */

module.exports.routes = { ...
```

In the same config folder I have created the file called is_ajax.js.

```
// Only run through API on ajax calls.
module.exports.isAjax = function(req, res, next){
  if (req.headers['x-requested-with']) {
    // Allow sails to process routing
    return next();
  } else {
    // Load main template file
    // ...
  }
};
```

My intended purpose is to make non-Ajax GET requests all load the same template file so my CanJS application can set up the application state based on the URL (so my javascript application is properly bookmark-able).

I would like to run that script as middleware.  **Can somebody please show me how to use app.use() in this case to have the is_ajax.js script run before other routing?**

I'm guessing it's something like

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use( require('./is_ajax') );
```

Only when I do the above, it tells me that it can't find the express module.  I've verified that express is a module inside Sails' node_modules.  Is there another syntax for loading it?  I'd rather not have to install a second copy of express alongside sails.  Is there a way to access the original Sails/Express app instance?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [policies](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-wiki/blob/0.9/policies.md) to achieve this.  Save your `isAjax` function as isAjax.js under your api/policies folder, and change it to just use `module.exports` instead of `module.exports.isAjax`.  Then in your config/policies.js file, you can specify which controllers/actions to apply the policy to--to run `isAjax` for every route, just do:

```
'*':'isAjax'
```

in that file.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue of figuring out how to make use of middlewares.
They are basically defined in the `config/policies.js`.
So, if you want to use **middlewares**(aka *policies*) like old style, you can do the following (this may not be the nicest way):

```
// config/policies.js
'*': [ 
  express.logger(),
  function(req, res, next) {
    // do whatever you want to
    // and then call next()
    next();
  }
]
```

However, the real **sailjs** way is to put all such policies in `api/policies/` folder

Comment: Thx. (+1) but I don't think I'll be writing it that way -- thx for the extra arrow in our quiver though.

Answer (score 4):

To add compress middleware of express, I find this thread and

[sails-middleware-example-issue](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/814) are very usefull.

1. install express local: `npm install express`
2. load express: `var exp = require('express')`
3. add customMiddleware  in `$app_dir/config/local.js`

> ```
> express: {
>     customMiddleware: function (app) {
>       console.log("config of Middleware is called");
>       app.use(exp.logger());
>       app.use(exp.compress());
>       app.use(function (req, res, next) {
>         console.log("installed customMiddleware is used");
>         next();
>       })
>     }
>   }
> ```

Comment: Just a note--you don't need to add Express as a dependency just to do custom middleware in Sails!  In your example you're utilizing other Express middleware in your custom function, which is fine, but if you're not doing that then you can skip steps 1 and 2.

Comment: "express:" is deprecated (in sails 0.12.1). use "http:"