# Sails.js - Change routing order (custom routes after blueprints)

Tags: express, sails.js

I am having a very similar issue to this post here: [How to use custom route middleware with Sails.js? (ExpressJS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548850/how-to-use-custom-route-middleware-with-sails-js-expressjs)

in that I want all non ajax requests (or all routes with the prefix /api) to load the same view, regardless of route. I have implemented the given answer in that question, but came across the issue that the policy is not called for any unspecified routes.

If I was to catch all routes so that the policy was called, all my blueprints would be overwritten.

Ideally, I would catch all routes last, after the blueprints, since every non API route should be sent to the front end.

I am using angularjs for the front end and want angular to deal with all non API routing.

I would rather not use a .htaccess file as I need to put session information into the page on it's initial load.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your use case is very similar to a HTTP 404 Error situation - you want all requests which don't satisfy blueprint (and possibly **route.js**) routes to be handled in the same manner.

From **api/responses/notFound.js**:

```
* NOTE:
* If a request doesn't match any explicit routes (i.e. `config/routes.js`)
* or route blueprints (i.e. "shadow routes", Sails will call `res.notFound()`
* automatically.
*/
```

You can have special handling code here which calls the appropriate view if the request path contains `/api`:

```
if (req.path.match('^/api')) {
  return res.view('your-view-here');
}
```

Comment: This totally answers the question for me! Thank you very much!