# Implementing prerender.io middleware in sails.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sails.js, prerender

I have an angular site running on a sails.js backend.  I am trying to implement the prerender.io service for my site so that my site can be indexed by search engines.

The problem I am running into is that the setup instructions for their node module are specifically for express.  Basically they want you to set up this middleware:

```
app.use(require('prerender-node').set('prerenderToken', 'r8c9lN6JsUMMfpzYNlht'));
```

Sails doesn't set up middleware this way, but rather through it's `policies` (for the most part, anyway).

This question was raised some time ago [here](https://github.com/prerender/prerender/issues/35), however it seems it was simply added to a list and never actually addressed.

I have also looked at this: [How to use custom route middleware with Sails.js? (ExpressJS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548850/how-to-use-custom-route-middleware-with-sails-js-expressjs)

and have attempted implementing the customMiddleware solution, but to no avail.

Any ideas how to set this up in sails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at this issue: https://github.com/prerender/prerender/issues/12

@talss89 was able to get it working using `config/http.js`:

```
module.exports.http = {
    middleware: {

     prerender: require('prerender-node').set('prerenderToken', 'YOUR_TOKEN'),
     order: [
       'startRequestTimer',
       'cookieParser',
       'session',
       'myRequestLogger',
       'bodyParser',
       'handleBodyParserError',
       'prerender',
       'compress',
       'methodOverride',
       'poweredBy',
       '$custom',
       'router',
       'www',
       'favicon',
       '404',
       '500'
     ]
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't dig down there far enough on that page.  It should also be noted that the set token should be appended to the require if using prerender.io