# Using app.use to set up some routes in sails.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js

First of all, the context. I'm using [agenda](https://github.com/rschmukler/agenda) to schedule tasks in my sails.js app. Agenda starts in a hook, after orm and some other hook have finished. So far everything is good. Then I discovered [agendash](https://github.com/joeframbach/agendash), a web interface to manage agenda tasks. And I don't manage to make it work with sails.js.

The problem is in following. This is how agendash should be used (from the doc):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// ... your other express middleware like body-parser

var Agenda = require('agenda');
var Agendash = require('agendash');

var agenda = new Agenda({mongo: 'mongodb://127.0.0.1/agendaDb'});
app.use('/agendash', Agendash(agenda));
```

And I can't find where I should put this. As I said, agenda is initialized in a hook, and then I save it as `sails.agenda`. So the only thing I really have to do is

```
app.use('/agendash', require('agendash')(sails.agenda))
```

But I'm not sure how I could add a new route like this, outside of `routes.js` (I cannot refer to `sails` in that file, it's undefined), and then protect this route with some policies (I want agendash to be available only to admin). 
If I get it right, this line should be run only once, so I cannot put it in `config.http` as middleware. But otherwise the router of sails.js will overwrite the route (at least if I put `sails.hooks.http.app.use('/agendash', require('agendash')(agenda))` in a hook, the route is not exposed).

So what should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution by using the `customMiddleware` in `config/http.js` where I could do `app.use`, protect the route by middlewares and eventually call `Agendash(agenda)(req, res, next)`.
For this to work I had to move agenda initialization out of the hook and put it inside `customMiddleware`. This is what my code looks like:

```
    customMiddleware: function(app){
        var Agenda = require("agenda");
        var Agendash = require('agendash')
        var agenda = new Agenda({db: {address: 'localhost:27017/dbName', collection: 'collectionName'}});
        //protect the route with several policies
        app.use('/agendash', function(req, res, next){
            require('../api/policies/policy1')(req, res, function(){
                require('../api/policies/policy2')(req, res, function(){
                    require('../api/policies/policy3')(req, res, function(){
                            Agendash(agenda)(req, res, next)
                        }
                    )
                })
            })
        });
        sails.agenda = agenda; //saving the reference
        agenda.on('ready', function(){
            var eventsToWaitFor = ['hook:orm:loaded', 'hook:email:loaded'];//if need to wait for some events before starting tasks
            sails.after(eventsToWaitFor, function(){
                require('./../api/services/jobs')(agenda);//loading all the jobs
                agenda.on('fail', function(err, job){
                    //log error here
                });
                agenda.every('10 minutes', 'task1');//schedule tasks
                agenda.every('10 minutes', 'task2');
                agenda.start();//start agenda
            });
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

First you should not init agenda in a hook but in `config/bootstrap.js` which is executed once on startup. Then you create a file called `config/myApp.js` where you put your global variables:

```
/**
 * Expose global variables.
 */
module.exports.myApp = {
    agenda: null
};
```

In `config/bootstrap.js` you set this variable once:

```
var Agenda = require('agenda');
sails.config.myApp.agenda = new Agenda({mongo: 'mongodb://127.0.0.1/agendaDb'});
```

Now you have a reference to agenda and you can access from everywhere in your app using `sails.config.myApp.agenda`.

To register the agendash route  you have to use a custom middelware as explained here [How to use custom route middleware with Sails.js? (ExpressJS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548850/how-to-use-custom-route-middleware-with-sails-js-expressjs/18562458#18562458) and discussed here https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/814

Comment: I finally managed to make it work. But first I'd like to comment:
I see the first two things which you suggested as excessive: you don't really need to put anything in `config/bootstrap.js`, neither you need the config file for the app. Moreover, hooks are also run only once, so they are ok for the task of initing agenda. The problem is that I can't `app.use` there. I found the solution by using the `customMiddleware` in `config/http.js` where I could do `app.use`, protect the route by middlewares and eventually call `Agendash(agenda)(req, res, next)`.

Comment: So I see your answer as giving some push, but being quite far from providing a solution. Moreover, you don't really explain anything (like why shouldn't I use hooks?). Also you don't answer the question of how to protect the route with the policies (I'm not using controllers, so `config/policies.js` is not an option). So I don't feel like I can accept your answer, but neither I feel like it would be correct to write my own, which I eventually found (and described above).

Comment: @amberv if you found a solution that suits you better then share it. I am sure there are multiple ways of solving this problem.